# Lines-of-code counting for many C# solutions

Tags: c#, file, count, lines-of-code

I am currently researching a solution for counting lines of code in C#.

I pretty much need a combination of the following two tools:
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/07/01/c-and-vbnet-line-count-utility/
http://www.locmetrics.com/index.html

My problem is that I need to recursively scan a folder containing a lot of visual studio solutions. So can't really use the first tool without any major work on its code, as it's only able to scan a single solution at a time.
But I also need to split the results for each solution, preferably even the contained projects. This disqualifies the second tool I found. I also found NDepend which suffers from the same problem.

Do you know of any free tools that do what I need? I am unable to find anything suitable.

Comment: Its also important that the tool is able to exclude comments. Maybe even auto-generated code. Sorry forgot
(can edit the original question, as Kobi already repaired the hyperlinks ;-) )

Comment: “Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight.” - Bill Gates

Comment: I am not sure what these numbers are going to be used for. At the moment they are just a onetime snapshot. Probably to get a sense of the size of all projects. I am just an intern asked to find out :-)

Comment: You could exclude auto generated files based on either partial filename or location, but you couldn't necessarily identify ALL autogenerated code.

Comment: The exclusion of auto-generated code is only a plus not a real requirement. But I was specifically asked to exclude comments.

Comment: Try GNU `find` and `wc`. ;)

Answer (score 22):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a great tool designed for measuring and visualising code metrics and complexity.

Powershell would do it:

```
(dir -Include *.cs -Recurse | select-string .).Count
```

[Counting Lines of Source Code in PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/18/counting-lines-of-source-code-in-powershell/):

Line count per path:

```
   gci . *.cs -Recurse | select-string . | Group Path
```

Min / Max / Averages:

```
   gci . *.cs -Recurse | select-string . | Group Filename | Measure-Object Count -Min -Max -Average
```

Comment ratio:

```
   $items = gci . *.cs -rec; ($items | select-string "//").Count / ($items | select-string .).Count


## Count the number of lines in all C# files in (and below) 
## the current directory. 

function CountLines($directory) 
{ 
    $pattern = "*.cs" 
    $directories = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($directory) 
    $files = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($directory, $pattern) 

    $lineCount = 0 

    foreach($file in $files) 
    { 
        $lineCount += [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file).Split("`n").Count 
    } 

    foreach($subdirectory in $directories) 
    { 
        $lineCount += CountLines $subdirectory 
    } 

    $lineCount 
} 

CountLines (Get-Location)
```

Also, [Line Counter](http://www.wndtabs.com/)

Comment: Unfortunatly this counts all text lines, I am more interested in real code lines, excluding comments for example and maybe even auto-generated code.

Comment: @Eric - your productivity is going to go way down if you don't count comments and auto-generated code.  :-)

Comment: Couldn't you use a combination of this method to find all the .sln files, then feed each of them into the first tool you mentioned?

Comment: @nc97217 sure I could come up with my own implementation, just hoped this has already been done

Comment: As far as I can tell NDepend also only works on a single solution/assembly at a time. But I need to scan the complete repository at once.

Comment: @Eric: that's true. But it does have many useful metrics; much more useful than simple line counts

Answer (score 3):

I think [LOCcode](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LOCCounter/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=115) is an interesting free tool for counting number of Lines Of Code. It allows to choose which of files must be processed. It counts LOC in all enabled tasks.

[image]

Unfortunately, it seems that development of LOCCode is over.

Comment: too bad it counts XMLs >.<

Comment: Link is dead and Wayback Machine can't help. :(

Answer (score 2):

What you need is logical lines of code counting as defined here:
 
[How do you count your number of Lines Of Code (LOC)](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2007/10/03/how-do-you-count-your-number-of-lines-of-code-loc.aspx)

If you use NDepend to count your number of [lines of code](http://www.NDepend.com) you can still append all your VS sln in a NDepend project. However logical lines of code is a metric inferred from PDB files so make sure that all your assemblies have corresponding PDB files associated.

Also you might be interested by:[Why is it useful to count the number of Lines Of Code (LOC) ?](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2007/10/05/why-is-it-useful-to-count-the-number-of-lines-of-code-loc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I liked what Mitch Wheat has said but I don't like some useless information is calculated as 'line of code'. I've written a C# code to find total number of REAL lines in the code here: 
http://rajputyh.blogspot.in/2014/02/counting-number-of-real-lines-in-your-c.html

**You need to build a small utility out of that code** to provide path of your root folder where all "*.cs" files are kept. Good thing about that code is that it is not dependent upon the project file. I generally check-out my code and delete auto generated files and the use the tool to count number of lines.

Answer (score -3):

In the end I went with [LocMetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/index.html), unfortunately this didn't really solve my per-solution problem.

But the folder structure of the reposiotry maps well enough to solutions so I was decided to use the tool above.

Thanks everybody for helping

Comment: Why did you down vote this answer? Should I have done something differently?